# USB camera displaying grey screen on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I have a C++ console application running on Windows 10 which uses OpenCV to display the internal webcam and a USB video camera side by side.

The code below works. I picked up the two streams and play them at 10fps.

When I take the code and use it in a C++ Windows Desktop application the internal webcam works fine but the USB video camera displays a grey screen.

I have tried to troubleshoot this problem and curiously when I use a breakpoint on

`imshow("Window 2", frame2);`

when I click to continue the USB video feed begins and works perfectly.

```
int main()
    {
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0, CAP_DSHOW);
    VideoCapture cap2;
    cap2.open(1, CAP_DSHOW);

if (!cap.isOpened())
{
    std::cout << "No " << cam1 << "\n";
    return -1;
}

if (!cap2.isOpened())
{
    std::cout << "No " << cam1 << "\n";
    return -1;
}

while (1) {

    Mat frame;
    Mat frame2;
    cap >> frame;
    cap2 >> frame2;

    if (frame.empty())
        break;
    if (frame2.empty())
            break;
        namedWindow("Window 1", 1);
        namedWindow("Window 2", 1);

    imshow("Window 1", frame);
    imshow("Window 2", frame2);

    char c = (char)waitKey(100);
    if (c == 27)
        break;
}
cap.release();
cap2.release();
destroyAllWindows();

waitKey(0);

return 0;
```

}

EDIT:

In the constructor for my main form which displays the window if I move the call to `InitializeComponent();` to after I have opened the captures both videos load perfectly. I assume it is an issue with generating the GUI and access the camera driver at the same time.

Comment: Maybe you meant    frame2.empty in second  if (frame.empty())?

Comment: @Nabi Sorry, you are correct. I have changed this but it has not fixed the problem. Thank you